# How to create repeatable table with unique ID's using jQuery

Tags: html, javascript, jquery

I need to create a table structure that can be "copied" and populated with a new set of data. However, each table must have unique IDs for functions that must access them later. For example:

```
<table class="main">
    <thead><tr><th class="header"></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row"><td class="col0"></td><td class="col1"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My current thought is to use jQuery to load the table from a seperate html file into a variable. Using this saved table I could then create a function that copies it, traverses the table to add an ID to each section where information will need to be appended from a seperate data source, and return this new table.

I am new to jQuery and feel like I may be missing an easier/better way to accomplish this. Any help on this subject would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example does not contain any `id`'s.  Where is your jQuery code?  What have you tried?  What _exactly_ are you trying to accomplish?  There might be a better way than injecting a `table` from a variable.

Comment: which element do you want to add the id to?

Answer (score 0):

You could clone table rows like this http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAECx/ but remember to set the id attribute with unique values like database ids,then on edit clicked,you can  get the id value you set and use it to delete or update.I suggest you look at the DOM topic in jquery.

Assuming you get the data via ajax,you can use this to set the unique id

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       var item = data[i];
       $('.client-content').append("<li id='"+item [0]+"'>"+"<b>"+i +"</b>" + " : " +item[0] + " : " + item[1]+"<a href='#' class='link-right'>Edit</a>" + "<a href='#' class='link-right'>Delete</a>"+"</li>" + "<br/>");
```

Hope that helps.